# Mongodb: Sort a list by key and value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a record fetched that I want to sort before sending to frontend.

```
db.getCollection('users').find({$or:
                    [
                       {createdBy: 'abhi'},
                       {createdBy: {'$ne': 'abhi'}, visibility: 'public'}
                    ]}).sort({'createdBy': 1})
```

I want to sort all the records for **createdBy** user **abhi** first and then the other users.

**Something like:**

```
.sort({'createdBy == abhi': 1})
```

Comment: You want to have all documents with the user `abhi`, first, and otther documents to come after, sorted in alphabetical order?

Comment: @SergiuZaharie, that ways I've to make two calls and then concat the records. Can't it be done by specifying sort on key and value basis?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that using aggregation.

1. Make a new projection of the documents fields and add a temp marking field `first: true` if the `createdBy` is `abhi` else `first: false`
2. Sort by `{first:-1, createdBy:1}` to put your marked fields first in the sorted list
3. (Re)Project your fields to remove the temp field `first`

code:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {$project: 
        {   
            first: 
            {
                $cond: { if: { "$eq": ["$createdBy", 'abhi' ]}, then: true, else: false }
            },
            createdBy: '$createdBy'
        }
    },
    {$sort: {first:-1, "createdBy": 1}},
    {$project: 
        {
            createdBy: 1
            // Don't include first:1
        }       
    }
])
```